# prependTo() not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for some reason the prependTo() function in jQuery is not working for me. It's probably something simple that I'm missing but I Can't see it at all. I'm basically just trying to get the last image to appear at the start through jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slide_count = $(".carousel li").length;
  var slide_width = $(".carousel li").width();
  var slide_height = $(".carousel li").height();
  var cont_width = slide_width * slide_count;
  
  $(".cont").css({ height: slide_height, width: slide_width});
  $(".carousel").css({ width: cont_width, marginLeft: - slide_width });
  $(".carousel li:last-child").prependTo(".carousel");
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;/*removes white space*/
  margin: 60px auto 0 auto;
}

.carousel{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
}

.carousel li{
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
  height: 350px;
}

.carousel li img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.next{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.prev{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <ul class="carousel">
    <div class="prev">
    </div>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-3.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <div class="next">
    </div>
  </ul>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `:last-child` is looking for children of the `li`, not the last `li` itself. You need to use `:last` instead:

```
$(".carousel li:last").prependTo(".carousel");
```

Also note that your HTML is invalid as you cannot have a `div` as a child of a `ul`. You'll need to put them outside the `ul` or inside another `li`.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. And yeah I just noticed that if I removed the divs it worked with last-child. I did not know that about uls I will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: I guess that issue is with improper `div` inside `ul`, not `:last-child`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slide_count = $(".carousel li").length;
  var slide_width = $(".carousel li").width();
  var slide_height = $(".carousel li").height();
  var cont_width = slide_width * slide_count;
  
  $(".cont").css({ height: slide_height, width: slide_width});
  $(".carousel").css({ width: cont_width, marginLeft: - slide_width });
  $(".carousel li").last().prependTo(".carousel");
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;/*removes white space*/
  margin: 60px auto 0 auto;
}

.carousel{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
}

.carousel li{
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
  height: 350px;
}

.carousel li img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.next{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.prev{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <ul class="carousel">
    <div class="prev">
    </div>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-3.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <div class="next">
    </div>
  </ul>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```